# NameError: global name 'Solution' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to create a class object to reverse the given list.
Example: Input = [1,2] and the expected output will be [2,1]

This is my code:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, nums):
        self.nums = nums
    def tryout (self):
        self.nums.reverse()
        print(self.nums)

p = ListNode([1,2])
p.tryout
```

However when I ran my code on Leetcode, it kept giving me the error below

```
NameError: global name 'Solution' is not defined
    ret = Solution().reverseList(param_1)
Line 33 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 43 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Can I check if there's any issue with my code? i tried to run on Jupyter and the codes work but it didnt work when i submit to Leetcode

Comment: Leetcode expects that you write a (pointless) class `Solution` which contains your code.

Comment: Do you have a cell in your Jupyter Notebook that declares `class Solution`? If so, you need to include that with your Leetcode submission.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Leetcode is expecting your class name to be `Solution` and your method name to be `reverseList`

Comment: Note that there must be a class named `Solution`. But you can also add any other classes you wish.